# RecyclerView notifydatasetchanged not invoked from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a home activity and 3 child fragments, in home activity i am invoked an api then i want to update the result to the recycler view that contained in fragment. now everything except notifydatasetchanged() is working perfectly.

have you any idea about fragments please help me.

**HomeActivity.java**

```
      // member variable for the first fragment

         private FeedsFragment feedsFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    // initialised in oncreate    
        feedsFragment = new FeedsFragment();

    }

        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(feedsFragment, "FEEDS");
}

// this is what i am called when get the api result
feedsFragment.setUpdateArrayList(updateArrayList);
```

**FeedsFragment.java**

```
    public class FeedsFragment extends Fragment {

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private UpdateListAdapter uAdapter;
        private ArrayList<Updates> updateArrayList;
        private String TAG = UpdatesActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        public FeedsFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            updateArrayList = new ArrayList<Updates>();

            View thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_updates, container, false);

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) thisView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_updates);

            uAdapter = new UpdateListAdapter(getActivity(), updateArrayList, new UpdateListAdapter.UpdatesActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShareButtonTapped(int position) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onOptionsButtonTapped(int position, View v) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProfileButtonTapped(int position) {

                }
            });

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(uAdapter);


            return thisView;
        }


        public void setUpdateArrayList(ArrayList<Updates> array){

            this.updateArrayList = array;
            this.recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

//Also tried 
// uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the data is being actually **added to the adapter** before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Comment: tested app with debugger with break points, array have 14 objects

Comment: You are calling `setUpdateArrayList()` from the Activity, try calling it inside the Fragment. ie from `onCreateView()` . and lemme know

Comment: try using **this.updateArrayList.clear();** then **this.updateArrayList.addAll(array);** in setUpdateArrayList() method before calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: bug fixed for now see answers

Comment: Thank you all . for supporting a lot.

Comment: @shhp I'm not sure but this should fix, as updateArrayList is used for adapter data and clear and adding the data will reflect a change, however referencing to any other array may not.

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh I think you are right :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you change the `updateArrayList` in the fragment rather than the list in the adapter.

You can add an api in `UpdateListAdapter` as

```
public void setData(List<Updates> data){...}
```

Then call that api in `setUpdateArrayList` before you call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for supporting me , the problem is temporarily fixed by reinitialize the upadatelistadapter

```
    public void setUpdateArrayList(ArrayList<Updates> array){

        this.updateArrayList = array;

       ********** <Reinitialized the adapter here >**********

        this.recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

Comment: instead of Re-initializing, try to clear the updateArrayList and then use addAll method to add array's data